# Further away objects overlapping close objects in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 3 different planes: foreground, middle ground, and background. Fore some reason the further back planes are periodically rendering over top of my foreground planes.

Here in the scene view you can see that the waves are closer to the camera then the background.
[image]

Yet in the game the background will sometimes show overtop of the closer planes, as shown in this screen shot:
[image]

I am using a perspective camera.

Comment: The unit tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to change the rendering order in your shader.  This solution won't generalize well because you'll need to have a unique shader for each plane.

So for example, to modify the [transparency order](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-SubshaderTags.html), you might have ShaderFar:

```
Shader "TransparentFar" {
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" }
        Pass {
            // rest of the shader body...
        }
    }
}
```

And ShaderNear:

```
Shader "TransparentNear" {
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent+1" } //**note the +1
        Pass {
            // rest of the shader body...
        }
    }
}
```

The built-in shaders can be [downloaded here](http://download-cdn.unity3d.com/unity/download/archive) and should be easily adaptable.